# Why does 'ng' keep showing 'command not found' in GitBash?

Tags: angular-cli, git-bash

I know this has been asked before but I really need help. I've uninstalled multiple times and reinstalled @anguler/cli but it still keeps telling me that 'ng' command isn't found when I type 'ng' into the terminal. I should also say that ng suddenly stopped working but I have no idea why or when. Additionally, all other 'ng' commands don't work. I poured over many websites and articles about this but I'm at a loss. I was given a lead that it may have to do with the file setup but I'm unsure of how to research that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you have to use npx {command} to access it. In this case it would be npx ng ...

Comment: npx ng works, I was able to make a new project and generate a component on that project. I appreciate the help! Any reason why it would make you enter the npx command into GitBash?

Answer (score -1):

Install @angular/cli and try npm update